# iOS CoreImage Edge detection

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am writing an iOS as and I need to be able to do edge detection in the image. I actually want something similar to Photoshop's trace contour. Since I basically need to get the simplest set of lines to work with.. Thing is I cannot seem to figure out how to do it and frankly I have 0 interest in OpenCV since I spent 5 hours today trying to get any of the 10 or so zips of it I downloaded to compile, in any way shape or form. 
So I was hoping maybe some one could point me the right way to do it with what's built in to the os.. or maybe an example

Comment: If you want something that's a little easier to integrate than OpenCV, my GPUImage open source framework has both Sobel and Canny edge detection: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage . They are also GPU-accelerated, making them quite a bit faster than OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If haven't used it myself, but are you looking for something like [this](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/)? It's basically a C++ wrapper and it declares a method called `ImageWrapper *cannyEdgeExtract(float tlow, float thigh)`.

Comment: well if it isn't what I was looking for it sure bears a close resemblance ;) thanks you so much